# Showing that if $p$ is prime, then $(p^4 + 4)$ can't be prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to show that if $p$ is prime, then $(p^4 + 4)$ can't be prime.

I guess Fermat's little theorem may help, but I can't figure out how to use it for the proof.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: modulo 5 all primes are 4th roots of 1 by Fermat (except 5, which you check separately)

Comment: Also, $x^4 + 4 = (x^2 + 2 x + 2)(x^2 - 2 x + 2)$

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity

Answer (score 4):

$x^4+4=(x^2-2 x+2) (x^2+2 x+2)$

$x^2-2 x+2 \ge 2$ for $x\ge 2$

$x^2+2 x+2 \ge 2$ for $x\ge 0$

So $n^4+4$ is never prime for $n\ge 2$.